# Getting multiple column values from subquery in SQL Server returns null

Tags: t-sql, join, subquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT p.IdS, 
       p.PID, 
       a.Destination, 
       d.DelDate, 
       d.DelTimeE, 
       d.DelTimeL,
       td.EDateTime, 
       td.ECode, 
       td.[Source]
FROM Parcel p
LEFT JOIN Party a ON p.IdS = a.IdS
LEFT JOIN DateAndTime d ON p.IdS = d.IdS
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT TOP(1) PID, 
               EDateTime, 
               ECode, 
               [Source] 
               FROM TgData 
               WHERE ECode='I' ORDER BY ID ASC) AS td
ON p.PID = td.PID
LEFT JOIN Ships s ON p.IdS = s.ShipId
WHERE s.IsFinalized='1' AND s.DComplete='2012-11-30' AND DelDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Destination ASC
```

But for some, for me unknown reason, the td columns are always "NULL" in the response from the database even though I KNOW that there are values that should be displayed there. The query executes in < 1 second

I also tried the other way around to do it like this:

```
        SELECT p.IdS, 
           p.PID, 
           a.Destination, 
           d.DelDate, 
           d.DelTimeE, 
           d.DelTimeL,
       (SELECT TOP(1) EDateTime FROM TgData WHERE ECode='I' AND PID=p.PID ORDER BY ID ASC) AS EDateTime
       (SELECT TOP(1) ECode FROM TgData WHERE ECode='I' AND PID=p.PID ORDER BY ID ASC) AS ECode
       (SELECT TOP(1) [Source] FROM TgData WHERE ECode='I' AND PID=p.PID ORDER BY ID ASC) AS [Source]
FROM Parcel p
LEFT JOIN Party a ON p.IdS = a.IdS
LEFT JOIN DateAndTime d ON p.IdS = d.IdS
LEFT JOIN Ships s ON p.IdS = s.ShipId
WHERE s.IsFinalized='1' AND s.DComplete='2012-11-30' AND DelDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Destination ASC
```

This gets the right data but the query takes 20 seconds to display 470 rows. :P

Any tips or hints would be lovely, I've been stuck in a train of thought for the last 24 hours around this.

Comment: can you post structure and sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
    p.IdS, 
    p.PID, 
    a.Destination, 
    d.DelDate, 
    d.DelTimeE, 
    d.DelTimeL,
    EDT.EDateTime AS EDateTime,
    EC.ECode AS ECode,
    TDL.Source as Source
FROM Parcel p
LEFT JOIN Party a ON p.IdS = a.IdS
LEFT JOIN DateAndTime d ON p.IdS = d.IdS
LEFT JOIN Ships s ON p.IdS = s.ShipId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PID , TOP(1) EDateTime FROM TgData WHERE ECode='I') as EDT ON EDT.PID = p.PID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PID , TOP(1) ECode FROM TgData WHERE ECode='I') AS EC ON EC.PID=p.PID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PID , TOP(1) Source FROM TgData WHERE ECode='I') AS TDL ON TDL.PID=p.PID
WHERE s.IsFinalized='1' 
    AND s.DComplete='2012-11-30' 
    AND DelDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Destination ASC
```

Comment: this is the derieved query. use it instead of dependant subquery you used in your second query example. It is faster.